# Query posts with double taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

So I have a custom type called "vendors" and two custom taxonomies for it. One is "state" and the other is "type".

I am trying to list all the vendors from a certain state on one page. I'm using the file called "taxonomy-state.php" which works perfectly. It displays all the vendors in the state.

Now what I want to do is specify the types of vendors in order. So the page will look something like this:

Vendors in "STATE":

Vendor Type #1:
      Vendor #1 
      Vendor #2 
      Vendor #3

Vendor Type #2:
      Vendor #1 
      Vendor #2 
      Vendor #3

I got it to display vendors by state. But I need to display them in the above layout.

I have an idea of how to do it. But I need to be able to make a query that can get a vendor from a certain state and certain vendor type.

Thanks in advanced,

Alain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully someone else will flesh out this answer, I don't have the time to write out a full solution right now...

If you're using WordPress 3.1, look at the `tax_query` parameter that you can pass to `query_posts`. It can handle multiple taxonomies and relationships between them.

Otto's post [WordPress 3.1: Advanced Taxonomy Queries](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/) is the best explanation I've seen of what tax queries can do, and how to use them...

In older versions of WP, you're stuck using a plugin [like this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/), or rolling your own fairly complex SQL queries.

Comment: I think this answer is quite complete. Use plugin linked or wait for 3.1 pretty much covers it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I decided to install 3.1 RC1 and do this. The plugin wasn't working out for me. Hopefully they launch the version soon. I don't want to leave the client with an unstable version.

Comment: Go for it. RC1 is already very stable and it sounds like the official release will be in a matter of weeks, if not sooner.

Answer (score 0):

For wp 3.0.x am using this function:

```
function posts_search ($post_type,$taxonomies) { // $taxonomies should be an array ('taxonomy'=>'term', 'taxonomy2'=>'term2')
foreach ($taxonomies as $key=>$value) {
    $args=array('post_type'=>$post_type,'post__in'=>$ids,$key=>$value,'showposts'=>-1);
    unset($ids); $ids=array();
    foreach($posts=get_posts($args) as $post) { $ids[]=$post->ID; }
    if (empty($ids)) return false;
}
return $posts;
```

}

and here's an exemple:

```
$posts = posts_search ('produtos',array('taxo1'=> 'term-aa','taxo2'=>'term-bb')); if($posts) { foreach($posts as $post) { ...
```

Allows me to query posts with two taxonomies parameters. If it can help.

Fyi, the function is not from me.